# file upload broken on node form on custom page

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [D7 Image field upload errors with custom node_add() form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/d7-image-field-upload-errors-with-custom-node-add-form)

I have a custom page with a node form on it. The problem is that when I try to upload an image I get lots of errors.

The code is like this:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$output = drupal_render(node_add('node_type'));
return $output;
```

Some of the errors I get are:

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'node_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 795 of E:\work\my_site\includes\form.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: #node in comment_form_node_form_alter() (line 1193 of E:\work\my_site\modules\comment\comment.module).
Notice: Undefined index: #node in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 630 of E:\work\my_site\modules\menu\menu.module).
```

The funny thing is that if I return the form array everything works well.

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$output = node_add('node_type');
return $output;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't help me at all.

This is the same problem as in [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/d7-image-field-upload-errors-with-custom-node-add-form) but the solution there is not an option for me.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, apparently you should add these line to the menu item array:

```
'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node'),
'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
```

it is not enough to just add `module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');` before printing the form.

Comment: This solved the problem for me!  I was also able to remove the module_load_include('inc','node','node.pages');  line from my page callback, it was no longer needed.