# File upload broken on node form

Tags: files

I have the same problem described in [I get image field upload errors with a custom node_add() form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/i-get-image-field-upload-errors-with-a-custom-node-add-form).

How do I add these lines to the menu item array?

```
'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node'),
'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
```

I get the following errors:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'node_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 800 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\includes\form.inc).
>   Notice: Undefined index: #node in comment_form_node_form_alter() (line 1194 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\comment\comment.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in comment_form_node_form_alter() (line 1211 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\comment\comment.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: #node in location_node_form_node_form_alter() (line 14 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\sites\all\modules\location\location_node.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in location_node_form_node_form_alter() (line 15 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\sites\all\modules\location\location_node.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: #node in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 629 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\menu\menu.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 629 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\menu\menu.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: #node in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 630 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\menu\menu.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in menu_form_node_form_alter() (line 630 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\menu\menu.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: #node in translation_form_node_form_alter() (line 135 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\translation\translation.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in translation_form_node_form_alter() (line 135 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\translation\translation.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: field_im in file_ajax_upload() (line 271 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\file\file.module).
>   Notice: Undefined index: #suffix in file_ajax_upload() (line 280 of C:\xampp\htdocs\semt1\modules\file\file.module).

I am using [this module](https://github.com/Itangalo/Node-creation-block--Drupal-7-).

Comment: This seems like a very localized issue concerning a non-Drupal hosted module.  You would probably be better off asking whoever wrote the original code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function yourmodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['system/ajax']['file path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'node');
  $items['system/ajax']['file'] = 'node.pages.inc';
}
```

Comment: I try this function  bus still same error when upload file

Comment: if you have another solution tell me about

Comment: did you flushed all chaches?

Comment: yes I clear all cache

Comment: Have you replaced `yourmodule` in the function's name with your actual module name?

Comment: of course yes ...

Comment: function block_create_node_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['system/ajax']['file path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'node');
  $items['system/ajax']['file'] = 'node.pages.inc';

}

Comment: does not have another solution?

Comment: sorry man, it worked for but I was using a custom page, not this module (block_create_node)

Comment: ok but how to use custom page?